# Aligning the height of the first and second column in Python Dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a probably simple problem that I cannot solve. I have two columns in my Python Dash dashboard, which are not aligned in height, see here:

[image]

What do I need to change in my code so that the two columns are on the same height?

Any help is much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    
            html.Div([

            html.Label('Material 1'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='s1m1s',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value=options1[0],
            ),
            
            html.Label('Material 1'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='s1mdf45',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value=options1[0],
            ),
           
           
        ], style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

            html.Div([
            
                
            html.Label('m3'),
            daq.NumericInput(
                id='s2m1_num',
                min=0,
                max=200,
                value=0,
                ),
            
            html.Label('m3'),
            daq.NumericInput(
                id='s2m2_num',
                min=0,
                max=200,
                value=0,
                ),

        ], style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'})


])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `'vertical-align': 'top'` to the `style` dictionaries of the two columns to make sure that they are aligned at the top, see below.

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_daq as daq

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    # first column
    html.Div(

        children=[

            html.Label('Material 1'),

            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='s1m1s',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3']],
                value='option_1',
            ),

            html.Label('Material 1'),

            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='s1mdf45',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3']],
                value='option_2',
            ),

        ],

        style={
            'width': '20%',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top',
        }

    ),

    # second column
    html.Div(

        children=[

            html.Label('m3'),

            daq.NumericInput(
                id='s2m1_num',
                min=0,
                max=200,
                value=0,
            ),

            html.Label('m3'),

            daq.NumericInput(
                id='s2m2_num',
                min=0,
                max=200,
                value=0,
            ),

        ],

        style={
            'width': '20%',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top',
        }

    )

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```